# .htaccess rule, redirecting old unexistent address to new address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is how are looking my old post adresses on a blog:

```
subdomain.domain.com/view/1310/article-title/
```

I'd like it when a visitor comes from Google on such an address, to be redirected like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/article-title/
```

I need to specify some details regarding the old/first link:

- **subdomain**, is a variable
- **view**, is a fixed word
- **1230**, cand be any number/id

I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.domain.com $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/view/(*)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Resulted on a big 500 error.

Site is ruling on a WordPress cms.

Thanks in advance!

---

Added after Michael Berkowski's answer. My current wp rules are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 500 error is a result of the `(*)` where the `*` (zero or more) has nothing preceding it as a qualifier.  You might have intended `(.*)` but what you really need in there is `[^/]+` to get all characters up to the next `/`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Slight modification of the subdomain - must escape .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# Note this may need to be ^view/ instead of ^/view
# In htaccess context the leading / should probably not be there
RewriteRule ^/view/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The above looks specifically for `subdomain.domain.com`, but since you specified it is variable, use this to get all subdomains except `www.domain.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Matches all subdomains except www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/view/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Failing this, post any other rewrite rules you may have (since you mentioned this is WordPress I expect you have other rules) because the order is likely to be significant.

#### Update incorporate WordPress rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The new rules handle the subdomain redirect...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]

# After which WordPress does its internal redirection
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited my question with my current rules. Tried second example and failed.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Place these _before_ your current set of WordPress rules.  Also, don't forget to change `^/view/` to `^view/`

Comment: I tried with incorporate example also, still 500 error. Changed only the domain name of course :) Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Then please look in your Apache error log to see what the error actually is. I just noticed that in my second and third examples, I had your original error copy/pasted still there `(*)`

Comment: Oh yeah, now the site is working fine. Accessing old unexistent url is not working, "Server not found". I think i wrote wrong the first url, `http://` is not needed. Sorry, my mistake. Tired after 12 hours of pushing codes :) Edited.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich "Server not found" means the domain is mistyped somewhere

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24987/discussion-between-gravuj-miklos-henrich-and-michael-berkowski)