# .htaccess rule, rewrite key in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say we have an url like this:

```
http://domain.com/?theme_of_site=parameter_value
http://domain.com/?type_of_site=parameter_value
```

- **domain.com** - stable/static, always the same
- **theme_of_site** & **type_of_site** - stable/static, the same when choosen
- **parameter_value** - dynamic

It's like to have always the url's like:

```
http://domain.com/?theme=parameter_value
http://domain.com/?type=parameter_value
```

How can I write this in .htaccess?

---

*For the below discussion:*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Start by redirecting the original links from type_of_site= to type=
# Only if the browser's original request contains the strings
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} theme_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} type_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme=%1&type=%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} theme_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme=%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} type_of_site=([^&]+)    
RewriteRule (.*) $1?type=%1 [L,R=301]

# Then, after performing the initial redirects to change the browser
# URL, rewrite the parameters internally

# Match both present:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} theme=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme_of_site=%1&type_of_site=%2 [L]

# Then match each individually
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} theme=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme_of_site=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?type_of_site=%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So your aim is to rewrite the paramaters from `theme_of_site` to simply `theme`?

Comment: Hi @Michael Berkowski , you again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033166/htaccess-rule-redirecting-old-unexistent-address-to-new-address) glad :D Yes, you are right, `theme_of_site` to `theme` and `type_of_site` to `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query string parameters need to be captured in `RewriteCond`. You can match `(theme|type)` and capture the value, then rewrite it internally using the `(theme|type)_of_site` in a `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Match the theme or type paramater in `%1` and capture its value in `%2`
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (theme|type)=([^&]+)
# Rewrite The parameter name to include _of_site using the values captured above
# for all URLs as captured in $1
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1_of_site=%2 [L]
```

The simple example above works only if *either* of the parameters is specified. If you need to be able to handle both at once like `example.com/?type=abc&theme=123` it gets a little more complex:

```
# Start by redirecting the original links from type_of_site= to type=
# Only if the browser's original request contains the strings
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} theme_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} type_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme=%1&type=%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} theme_of_site=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme=%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} type_of_site=([^&]+)    
RewriteRule (.*) $1?type=%1 [L,R=301]

# Then, after performing the initial redirects to change the browser
# URL, rewrite the parameters internally

# Match both present:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} theme=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme_of_site=%1&type_of_site=%2 [L]

# Then match each individually
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} theme=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?theme_of_site=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?type_of_site=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I can match `theme` or `type` parameters with the same .htaccess code even if i decide later to use it on a test environment like sub.domain.com ?

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Yes. The domain name isn't taken into account at all here. It will work on any domain, and with any URL path.

Comment: I'm ashamed. It's not working again from the first run :) Added after "RewriteEngine On" and before any other WP specific rule.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Comment out the wordpress rules and test it with `[L,R]`.  If a wordpress rule subsequently matches with out `[QSA]` (query string append), it is probably removing the query string.  Or just add `[QSA]` to the WP rules.

Comment: no change. I tried with `[L,R]`, with WP rules commented out and with `[QSA]` way.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding? What I have above will rewrite the end-user's URL from type= to type_of_site=.  Do you need also to _redirect_ the user into `type=` if he supplies `type_of_site=` from the browser?

Comment: i need exactly the reversed way. `type_of_site` to `type` and not as you wrote in the above comment. Yes, I need also the redirect into `type`. And if possible to rewrite also the link clicked before.

Comment: So the end user always sees `type=` and never sees `type_of_site=`?

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich Ok, I added the redirects. Hopefully now it works more as expected

Comment: yes, thank you. Only that it adds a space and `HTTP/1.1` after the parameter's value.

Comment: Are type & theme always alphanumeric?  Easiest would be to replace `[^&]+` with `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Comment: they are always words. I replaced them which resulted in: `?type=cultural&type_of_site=cultural`

Comment: That would seem to imply there is still a `[R]` or `[QSA]` present for debugging which I don't have above ?

Comment: no, separated, `theme` or `type`. That is an awesome setup. Thank you. I wasin rush so I have rewritten the parameters name into the required short ones :P but I will take in consideration in the future this rules. Thank you very much!